C# NHibernate JOIN with a CASE WHEN clause
I have a class MedicalRecord that includes a bunch of information about a patient, and now this class references itself (nullable) in cases when the Medical Record was create on duplicity, the user can join this and the duplicated object will apoint to the main Medical Record one.
public class MedicalRecord {
   //...
   public virtual MedicalRecord MedicalReportUnified { get; set }
   public virtual PersonInfo PersonInfo { get; set; }
   public virtual List<Appointment> Appointments { get; set; }
}

I need to do a criteria query for Appointments that will get the PersonInfo of the main MedicalRecord if it exists, I managed to do it on SQL SERVER
SELECT * FROM appointments app
INNER JOIN medical_record mr 
ON app.id_medical_record = mr.id
LEFT JOIN medical_record main_mr
ON mr.id_main_medical_record = main_mr.id
INNER JOIN person_info pi
ON pi.id = (CASE WHEN main_mr.id IS NOT NULL THEN main_mr.id_person ELSE mr.id_person)

Is there a way to do this on ICriteria of NHibernate? I'm using version 4.0
I already use the .CreateCriteria for the main MedicalReport and set Projections.Conditional to check, but it became a lot heavier and this changes should be all over the system, so duplicate the joins is not a solution.
